# SQL/Postgres - collapse every N rows into 1 based on row position in group

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a set of ordered results from a Postgres table, where every group of 4 rows represents a set of related data. I want to process this set of results further, so that every group of 4 rows are collapsed into 1 row with aliased column names where the value for each column is based on that row's position in the group - I'm close, but I can't quite get the query right (nor am I confident that I'm approaching this in the optimal manner). Here's the scenario:

I am collecting survey results - each survey has 4 questions, but each answer is stored in a separate row in the database. However, they are associated with each other by a submission `event_id`, and the results are guaranteed to be returned in a fixed order. A set of `survey_results` will look something like:

```
  event_id   |    answer
----------------------------
     a       |     10
     a       |     foo
     a       |     9
     a       |     bar
     b       |     2
     b       |     baz
     b       |     4
     b       |     zip
```

What I would like to be able to do is query this result so that the final output comes out with each set of 4 results on their own line, with aliased column names.

```
event_id  |  score_1  |  reason_1  |  score_2  |  reason_2
----------------------------------------------------------
    a     |   10      |    foo     |     9     |    bar
    b     |   2       |    baz     |     4     |    zip
```

The closest that I've been able to get is

```
SELECT survey_answers.event_id,
    (SELECT survey_answers.answer FROM survey_answers FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY) AS score_1,
    (SELECT survey_answers.answer FROM survey_answers OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY) AS reason_1
    (SELECT survey_answers.answer FROM survey_answers OFFSET 2 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY) AS score_2,
    (SELECT survey_answers.answer FROM survey_answers OFFSET 3 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY) AS reason_2
FROM survey_answers
GROUP BY survey_answers.event_id
```

But this, understandably, returns the correct number of rows, but with the same values (other than `event_id`):

```
event_id  |  score_1  |  reason_1  |  score_2  |  reason_2
----------------------------------------------------------
    a     |   10      |    foo     |     9     |    bar
    b     |   10      |    foo     |     9     |    bar
```

How can I structure my query so that it applies the `OFFSET`/`FETCH` behaviors every batch of 4 rows, or, maybe more accurately, within every unique set of `event_id`s?

Comment: We can't answer this without seeing a third column which provides the order for each item in an `event_id` group.

Comment: @skwidbreth . . . "the results are guaranteed to be returned in a fixed order".  You don't understand databases or Postgres.  Tables represent *unordered* sets.  The only ordering is by using columns or expressions with an `order by` clause.  If you have no column that contains the ordering information, you cannot do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=9cc189a8fb74298a2c1c6c4457dabd88)

First of all, this looks like a very bad design:

1. There is no guaranteed order! Databases store their data in random order and call them in random order. You really need a order column. In this small case this might work for accident.
2. You should generate two columns, one for score, one for reason. Mix up the types is not a good idea.

Nevertheless for this simple and short example this could be a solution (remember this is not recommended for productive tables):

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT 
        *,
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY event_id)    -- 1
    FROM 
        survey_results
)
SELECT
    event_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN row_number = 1 THEN answer END) AS score_1,    -- 2
    MAX(CASE WHEN row_number = 2 THEN answer END) AS reason_1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN row_number = 3 THEN answer END) AS score_2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN row_number = 4 THEN answer END) AS reason_2
FROM
    data
GROUP BY event_id
```

1. The row_number() [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) adds a row count for each `event_id`. In this case from 1 to 4. This can be used to identify the types of `answer` (see intermediate step in fiddle). In productive code you should use some order column to ensure the order. Then the window function would look like `PARTITION BY event_id ORDER BY order_column`
2. This is a simple pivot on `event_id` and the type id (row_number) which does exactly what you expect

Comment: Thank you! I didn't design the table/schema, just got stuck with it.

Comment: @S-Man . . . Databases do not store their data in a random order.  Actually, the storage can be quite deterministic.  The rules of SQL queries specify that the ordering of a query -- no matter how simple -- is *indeterminate* (NOT "random") -- unless an `ORDER BY` is used.

Comment: I just wanted to formulate it as easy as possible :) But thank you for precising it!

Comment: Unfortunately, this table does not have any fields that I can `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 2):

You need a column that specifies the ordering.  In your case, that should probably be a `serial` column, which is guaranteed to be increasing for each insert. I would call such a column `survey_result_id`.

With such a column, you can do:

```
select event_id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then answer end) as score_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then answer end) as reason_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then answer end) as score_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then answer end) as reason_2
from (select sr.*,
             row_number() over (partition by event_id order by survey_result_id) as seqnum
      from survey_results sr
     ) sr
group by event_id;
```

Without such a column, you cannot reliably do what you want, because SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon. You're right, my knowledge of databases/Postgres is limited. This isn't a table/schema that I designed, just one I got stuck with, trying to make the best out of it.

Comment: You had actually answered a related question I posted, where I had a unique ID for each field - that's the way I would ideally like to handle this query, but unfortunately, those IDs may change over time and can't be consistently relied on...